# AttributeError: 'ParseResult' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, attributeerror, urlparse

```
def getPeopleLinks(page):
    links = []
    for link in page.find_all('a'):
        url = link.get('href')
        if url:
            if 'profile/view?id=' in url:
                links.append(url)
    return links

def getID(url):
    pUrl = urlparse(url)
    return pUrl.id
```

## execution from below

```
people = getPeopleLinks(page)
if people:
    for person in people:
        ID = getID(person)
```

when I execute it I get this error:

```
   return pUrl.id
AttributeError: 'ParseResult' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: What did you expect to be returned instead?

Answer (score 0):

The `urlparse()` function doesn't parse out the query string into key-value pairs; it only returns the constituent parts of the URL (which includes the query string part, but also the scheme, the hostname, the fragment identifier, etc).

You'll need to parse out the query string after extracting it from the URL; use the [`urllib.parse.parse_qs()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

def getID(url):
    query_string = urlparse(url).query
    return parse_qs(query_string)['id'][0]
```